# Error of filters in primefaces 8.0 on table with row virtualization enabled

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I am using Primefaces 8.0.
A table with frozen columns and filters on columns in the frozen part and scrolling part. Row virtualization enabled.

Button code:

```
<p:commandLink partialSubmit="true" process="@this" action="#{controller.loadCars}"  update=":form:tab1">
    <h:outputText value="Submit"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

Table code:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:dataTable
        id="tab1"
        scrollable="true"
        scrollHeight="350"
        scrollWidth="900"
        frozenColumns="2"
        var="car"
        scrollRows="5"
        virtualScroll="true"
        lazy="true"
        rows="5"
        rowIndexVar="#"
        value="#{model.cars}"
        widgetVar="carsTable"
        emptyMessage="No cars found with given criteria"
        filteredValue="#{model.filteredCars}">
        <p:ajax event="filter"  />
        <p:columnGroup groupRow="true" type="frozenHeader" >
        <p:row>
            <p:column field="1" headerText="Id"  filterBy="#{car.id}" filterMatchMode="contains"  >
                <p:inputText style="width:90%;"
                            onchange="PF('carsTable').filter()"
                            onkeyup="PF('carsTable').filter()"
                            onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false; }">
                </p:inputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column field="2" headerText="Color" filterBy="#{car.color}" filterMatchMode="contains" >
                <p:inputText style="width:90%;"
                            onchange="PF('carsTable').filter()"
                            onkeyup="PF('carsTable').filter()"
                            onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false; }">
                </p:inputText>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
        </p:columnGroup>
        <p:columnGroup groupRow="true" type="scrollableHeader">
        <p:row>
            <p:column headerText="Id" width="100"/>
            <p:column field="4" headerText="Year" filterBy="#{car.year}" filterable="true" filterMatchMode="contains" width="100">
                <p:inputText style="width:90%;"
                            onchange="PF('carsTable').filter()"
                            onkeyup="PF('carsTable').filter()"
                            onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false; }">
                </p:inputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Brand" width="100"/>
            <p:column headerText="Color" width="100"/>
            <p:column headerText="Id" width="100"/>
            <p:column headerText="Year" width="100"/>
            <p:column headerText="Brand" width="100"/>
            <p:column headerText="Color" width="100"/>
            <p:column headerText="Id" width="100"/>
            <p:column headerText="Year" width="100"/>
            <p:column headerText="Brand" width="100"/>
            <p:column field="3" sortBy="#{car.color}" filterBy="#{car.color}" headerText="Color2" filterMatchMode="contains" width="100" >
                <p:inputText style="width:90%;"
                            onchange="PF('carsTable').filter()"
                            onkeyup="PF('carsTable').filter()"
                            onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false; }">
                </p:inputText>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
        </p:columnGroup>
        <p:column headerText="Id" >
        <h:outputText value="#{car.id}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Color" >
        <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Year">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Brand">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Color">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Year">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Brand">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Color">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Year">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Brand">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Color">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column groupRow="true" headerText="Color2" >
        <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Controller

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Controller implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private Model model;


    public void loadCars(){
        model.getCars().clear();
        List<Car> tempCars = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
            tempCars.add(new Car( UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8), model.getBrands().get((int)(Math.random() * 10)), String.valueOf((int)(Math.random() * 50 + 1960)), model.getColors().get((int) (Math.random() * 10)), (int) (Math.random() * 100000), (Math.random() > 0.5) ? true: false ));
        }
        model.getCars().addAll(tempCars);
    }
}
```

Model

```
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import lombok.Data;

@Named
@SessionScoped
@Data
public class Model implements Serializable {

    Model(){
        colors = new ArrayList<>();
        colors.add("Black");
        colors.add("White");
        colors.add("Green");
        colors.add("Red");
        colors.add("Blue");
        colors.add("Orange");
        colors.add("Silver");
        colors.add("Yellow");
        colors.add("Brown");
        colors.add("Maroon");

        brands = new ArrayList<>();
        brands.add("BMW");
        brands.add("Mercedes");
        brands.add("Volvo");
        brands.add("Audi");
        brands.add("Renault");
        brands.add("Fiat");
        brands.add("Volkswagen");
        brands.add("Honda");
        brands.add("Jaguar");
        brands.add("Ford");
    }

    private List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Car> filteredCars;
    private List<String> colors;
    private List<String> brands;
}
```

Object

```
public class Car implements Serializable {

    public String id;
    public String brand;
    public String year;
    public String color;
    public int price;
    public boolean sold;

    public Car() {}

    public Car(String id, String brand, String year, String color) {
        this.id = id;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.year = year;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Car(String id, String brand, String year, String color, int price, boolean sold) {
        this.id = id;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.year = year;
        this.color = color;
        this.price = price;
        this.sold = sold;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }
    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public boolean isSold() {
        return sold;
    }
    public void setSold(boolean sold) {
        this.sold = sold;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 59 * hash + (this.id != null ? this.id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Car other = (Car) obj;
        if ((this.id == null) ? (other.id != null) : !this.id.equals(other.id)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

If turn off row virtualization, then filters in tables then all ok.

JS error from primefaces library occurs when filtering data into tables.

```
Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "children", b.bodyTable is undefined
    oncomplete http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/components.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:12
    v http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:18
    jQuery 6
    send http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:18
    offer http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:18
    handle http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:18
    ab http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:18
    filter http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/ line 2 > injectedScript:1
    callBehavior http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:22
    filter http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/components.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:12
    filterTimeout http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/components.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:12
    setTimeout handler*bindFilterEvent/< http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/components.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:12
    jQuery 2
components.js.xhtml:12:31834
    oncomplete http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/components.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:12
    v http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:18
    jQuery 6
    send http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:18
    offer http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:18
    handle http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:18
    ab http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:18
    filter http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/ line 2 > injectedScript:1
    callBehavior http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:22
    filter http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/components.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:12
    filterTimeout http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/components.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:12
    (Асинхронный: setTimeout handler)
    bindFilterEvent http://localhost:8080/jsf_html4+PR8/javax.faces.resource/components.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=8.0:12
    jQuery 2
```

Comment: Do you load your own jQuery?

Comment: No. Using  <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js"/>

Comment: You don't need to do that h:outputScript for jquery Primefaces loads it automatically.

Comment: Deleted the h:outputScript connection. The error remains..